# What determines whether or not you get a bomb at the end of a stage?

Tags: bit-trip-core

At the end of each section of each level in Bit Trip Core, you get a bomb — until you don't, then you stop getting bombs. What determines when you get bombs and when you don't? Is it enough to drop into Nether once to stop getting bombs for the rest of the track?

Comment: When did you stop getting bombs?  Are you sure this isn't a bug or glitch?

Comment: @DavidStarkey It happens rather regularly, typically I got 4 or 5 and then no more.